# How to unbind Trigger event added from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a button in html file which performs form submit.The code which binds to button for form submit comes from js file as below.The js file is a core file which is used across multiple pages hence the code in js file cannot be changed.

**Test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnClickMe").click(function(){
        $("#frmTable").trigger('submit');           
    });
});
```

HTML code is as shown below

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnClickMe").click(function(){
        $("#frmTable").off('trigger');
    });
});
</script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmTable" id="frmTable">

    </form>
    <input type="button" name="btnClickMe" id="btnClickMe" value="Click Me"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to override the trigger property attached to button so the form submission does not happen.

I tried a few workaround but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$("#btnClickMe").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
           OR
     event.stoppropagation();
});
```

Put this code in your html file so that you will not have to change your js file.
Try this and I think this will work.

Comment: Whoever voted this down just let me know the reason behind it please.

Comment: I checked it many times before posting. Better try giving some comments for voting down.

Comment: I guess u have some javascript error check the code again

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!i5UjSBRb!7X_3rb0f-9Zfguo_hgHz4hKpAKL2rLkZKIOoxFeulUE

Check the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59978/discussion-between-java-beginner-and-yunus).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
       $("#btnClickMe").unbind('click').click(function(event){
          .
          .
       });
     }); 
</script>
```